# Упаковка java .jar в single exe

Tags: java

Как упаковать java приложение в один exe с встроенной java jre? Нужно, чтобы один .exe при запуске запускал jar файл на встроенной jre. Главное, чтобы все из одного .exe файла.

Может быть PE архив создать? Есть ли проверенное решение?

Comment: Вот тут подробно описано как сделать исполняемый exe файл из JAR:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-executable

Comment: http://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-Eclipse

Comment: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ проверенное решение, пробуйте