# jar с внешними банками в exe

Tags: java, jar, exe

У меня есть два jar файла, один лежит в lib, соответственно все работает. Есть ли способ засунуть все это добро в один exe файл ?!

структура проекта для лучшего восприятия :
project
-lib
--Tools.jar
-Main.jar

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588415/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567171/178576) и т.д. рекурсивно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать исполняемый файл(exe) из своей программы написаной на java, не требующий от пользователя установленной java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596589/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bbexe-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83)